# TIDEMAN CS50-how can i check if the pair.winner is a winner elsewhere, i.e we have more than 1 edge going from some candidate

Tags: c, cs50, depth-first-search

this is my third day solving the imfamous **Tideman pset3** from cs50, day 2 had me stuck on the logic (which i feel the descripition of the problems misguided me from), [this git post](https://gist.github.com/nicknapoli82/6c5a1706489e70342e9a0a635ae738c9) helped my headbulb glow

i have implemented the logic explained in the link given above, how it works is as follows

---

## Function *lock_pair*

The first pairs from the sorted pairs is locked into the `locked[][]` using a loop going througt pair index
then it calls the `iscycle` function (defined by me) , and passes the index number (aka `i`) and winner of current pair (aka `original_winner`). It as also sets all values of `visitedbycycle` bool array as false before each call to `iscycle`

## Function * iscycle*

The `iscycle` starts with a loop , in the loop it first checks for the base case where it compares the loser current pair( pair updates with recursion) we have with the `orginal_winner`.
After the base case it checks if the current pair loser is marked winner somewhere in the `locked[][]`
2d array ,also also checks if the current pair loser is visited by set to false .
Inside the second conditional statement there is a loop going till pair count,
inside this loop it checks if the the second loser over whom the original loser won when checked in locked array is same as the `original_winner`, if yes then its updates the `visitedbycycle` to true and calls the function `iscycle` (recursion).

## Global Declarations by me

```
bool visitedbycycle[MAX];
bool iscycle(int pair_index, int original_winner);
```

---

## CODE

```
// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count ; i++)
    {
        locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
        for(int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            visitedbycycle[j] = false;
        }
        if (iscycle(i, pairs[i].winner))
        {
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = false;
        }
    }
    return;
 }

bool iscycle(int pair_index, int original_winner)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (pairs[pair_index].loser == original_winner)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if(locked[pairs[pair_index].loser][i] == true && visitedbycycle[i] != true)
        {
             for (int j = 0; j < pair_count ; j++)
            {
                if (pairs[j].winner == i )
                {
                    visitedbycycle[i] = true;
                    return iscycle(j, original_winner);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

i have tried having another function which will handle the for loop inside this conditional stament in `iscycle`

```
        if(locked[pairs[pair_index].loser][i] == true && visitedbycycle[i] != true)
        {
             for (int j = 0; j < pair_count ; j++)
            {
                if (pairs[j].winner == i )
                {
                    visitedbycycle[i] = true;
                    return iscycle(j, original_winner);
                }
            }
        }
```

the for loop currently only checks for the a sigle win/edge of one candidate over other and doesnt consider the case where we will have more than 1 win over other eg A --> B , A --> C,in this case it would only check for A-->B , and this is where im getting the `check50` error

```
:( lock_pairs skips final pair if it creates cycle
    lock_pairs did not correctly lock all non-cyclical pairs
```

the other two conditions are coming out correct

```
:) lock_pairs locks all pairs when no cycles
:) lock_pairs skips middle pair if it creates a cycle
```

my approach to solve this issue is to have another function called `more_cycles` which checks for more cycles and returns true or false , the for logic is added to it and and if statement now calls the `more_cycles` fucntion

## CODE

```
bool iscycle(int pair_index, int original_winner)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (pairs[pair_index].loser == original_winner)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if(locked[pairs[pair_index].loser][i] == true && visitedbycycle[i] != true)
        {
            int temp = more_cycles(i, original_winner);

            if ( temp == -1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return iscycle(temp, original_winner);
            }

        }
    }
    return false;
}

int more_cycles(int index, int original_winner)
{
    visitedbycycle[index] = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < pair_count ; j++)
            {
                if (pairs[j].winner == index )
                {
                    return j;
                }
            }
            return -1;
}
```

Comment: Although a link can be helpful, the question should contain all information necessary to understand the problem -- it should not be behind a link. Please provide input for which your code fails, what the wrong output is, and what is expected instead. The last paragraph of text in your post seems to suggest that you solved the issue... Please remove the *history* of what you tried, and only focus on the current code you have a problem with. Provide your code in one block, and make sure it is runnable and reproduces the issue.

Comment: i did try to implement more_cycles, but couldnt do so, and the input for which my code is failing is for when there is a candidate with more pair wins, my code iterates over only the first pair win and tries to find a cycle for there to the original winner,all other pair win(s) are ignored, from here comes  the check50 error for '( lock_pairs skips final pair if it creates cycle
    lock_pairs did not correctly lock all non-cyclical pairs'

Comment: I can only repeat what I wrote above.